# MASM x86 Access Violation While Running Loop

Tags: arrays, exception, assembly, masm, irvine32

I have an array of two-byte integers, which I am populating with random 3 digit numbers, using ESI to walk through the array. I am getting an access violation when I attempt to access the 9th element of the array and store it in ESI.

```
ARRAYSIZE = 200

.data
list        WORD    ARRAYSIZE   DUP(?)

fillArray PROC
    push    OFFSET list
    mov     esi, [esp] ;GET ADDRESS OF FIRST ELEMENT INTO ESI
    mov     ecx, request ;NUMBER OF ELEMENTS TO BE ADDED

ArrFill:
    ;calculate random 3-digit number, store in eax
    dec     ecx
    mov     [esi], eax ;THIS IS THE LINE THAT THROWS THE EXCEPTION
    sub     esi, 2
    cmp     ecx, 0
    jnz     ArrFill
```

Exception thrown: Access violation writing location 0x00405FFE (The value of ESI when thrown).

When I change the array to four-byte integers, I also get an access violation for trying to access the 5th element of the array at the same address.

Comment: How big is the array, each value is 16 bit but how many values did you allow for?

Comment: EDIT: Updated code to add more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> push    OFFSET list
> mov     esi, [esp] ;GET ADDRESS OF FIRST ELEMENT INTO ESI
> ```

Why not simply assign the offset to ESI with `mov esi, OFFSET list`

> ```
> mov     [esi], eax ;THIS IS THE LINE THAT THROWS THE EXCEPTION
> ```

Since the array contains **words** you can only write the contents of AX, not EAX! Use `mov [esi], ax`

> ```
> sub     esi, 2
> ```

To progress through the array you need to **add to the pointer** not subtract from it. Use `add esi, 2`

Comment: Thank you very much. I will take this into consideration.

Answer (score -1):

Hudspero

You are getting an access violation because you are trying to write ***past*** the array boundary.

Few things:

1. You don't seem to be initializing `ecx`. You should initialize this to the size of the array.
2. As you are `cmp ecx,0` you should be decrementing `ecx` before the comparison
3. You should move the `esi`address adjustment after you ensure you won't write past the boundary. I would restructure the code to test ecx for zero and jump out if true, otherwise decrement `esi`and jump back to `ArrFill`

Comment: I included the line
    ;using ecx as counter
specifically to reference the fact that I am using ECX. I did not think it was necessary to include it but I will now.